# Hugs Permutations Sufficient Space

Tags: haskell, hugs

First of all, yeah I know that I should use ghc instead (but we are forced to use hugs in the course)

So I try to generate all permutations of `[1 .. 9]` but when evaluating this, hugs throws an error:
"ERROR - Garbage collection fails to reclaim sufficient space"

Is there any quickfix or roundabout for this?

Comment: How have you defined your permutations function?

Comment: How can we help you without seeing how you implemented the permutations generator?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when writing such functions is that *prepending is basically always better than appending*.  If you have some list `xs`, then `1:xs` and `2:xs` will *share* `xs`, whereas `xs ++ [1]` and `xs ++ [2]` will each make their own copy of it.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the problem isn't because of Hugs, but because your permutation function is written in a way which is preventing garbage collection, or just otherwise allocating too much memory.

The following definition of permutations works for `[1..9]` in both GHC and Hugs for me (although `permutations [1..9]` in Hugs requires the garbage collector to be called a staggering 58 times on my computer)

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations (x:xs) = concatMap insertEverywhere (permutations xs)
  where insertEverywhere [] = [[x]]
        insertEverywhere (y:ys) = (x:y:ys): (map (y:) $ insertEverywhere ys)
```

Comment: Calling the garbage collector a lot isn't a big deal as long as the working set stays small, and the working set there should stay within a multiple of the list length, if my cursory analysis is right.